# How can I create an async java desktop client?

Tags: java, servlets

I must create a desktop java client that comunicate to a servlet in order to receive some notificationes.
The servlet is an async servlet but my doubt is with the client.
How is the best way to "listen" a response from the server. I looked to the httpcomponents-asyncclient from apache, but I´m not trully convinced about that library. Maybe an infinite loop?

Comment: how does the server notify the client that a response is complete and ought to be downloaded and is available?

Comment: Just to test, I am using a PrintWriter to print a string on a simple html, but I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out [netty](http://netty.io/), it's what we use for our IntelliJ IDEA real time collaboration plugin to communicate with our remote server. It's very simple to get started with and abstracts all the hard parts, including creating secure connections. [This is the netty user guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html), it should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) from Apache is very common
(be careful not to use [the old one](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)). [Check a simple example.](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchange.java)

Do you need to be constantly waiting for responses? If so, this is not the correct direction! The client should not have to call any method to get notifications... it should just be listening to some [socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) that the server writes to... Or just processing some queue. Perhaps you need to consider learning a bit of real time technologies and methods.

Comment: I saw that example! And yes, I need to be contantly waiting for a response from the server, I thought that servlet 3 with async methods is one way. What do you suggest using a webapp in tomcat 7 server and swing client?

Comment: an async call justs avoids to block the call waiting for the response!.. no "waiting for more" included.

well... depends if you want to use a framework or low level stuff. for low level, go for sockets. for high level, check @Bjorn Tipling answer.

Comment: I was cheking netty, but the idea of create one server inside another and open a port sounds no convincing to me becouse remember I´m using tomcat, so .. I don´t kwnow...

Comment: If you want to simplify, why don't you poll?